# SSN and 9 number screening issues

Tags: regex

This regex is looking for Social Security Numbers (SSNs) in several formats, but it also ignores obviously non-valid SSNs like 123-45-6789 or 000-00-0000, etc.

This expression should find a Social Security Number that :

- Contains any non-numeric delimiter (i.e. `###-##-####`,
  `###.##.####`, or `### ### ####`)
- It should also catch 9 digits in
  sequence with no delimiter, but bounded by whitespace (i.e. `text

  ### text`, or`### ######### ###`)
- This expression will ignore a Social Security Number that : Contains all zeroes in any specific group(i.e. `000-##-####`, `###-00-####`, or `###-##-0000`)
- Begins with `666`
- Begins with any value from `900-999`
- Is equal to `078-05-1120` (due to the Woolworth's Wallet Fiasco)
- Is equal to `219-09-9999` (appeared in an advertisement for the Social Security
  Administration)
- Contains all matching values(i.e. `000-00-0000`, `111-11-1111`, `222-22-2222`, etc.)
- Contains all incrementing values (i.e. `123-45-6789`)

Regex

```
(@"(?!\b(\d)\1+\D?(\d)\1+\D?(\d)\1+\b)(?!123\D?45\D?6789|219\D?09\D?9999|078\D?05\D?1120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})(?<!\d)\d{3}\D?(?!00)\d{2}\D?(?!0{4})\d{4}(?!\d)(?<!\d{5}-\d{4})",
```

The problem is we catch other entries that resemble those but we need to be specific enough these aren't caught.

Such as -

```
 (xxxx) xxx-xx-xxxx

 684072943 (and order number etc.)

 FA300217F0090

 Potential Match #1:--------------- nt: ex: 201[[71230 0821]] am ex: 201[[71230 0821]] am 26 JUNE 2012 ---------------Potential Match #2:--------------- am ex: 201[[71230 0821]] am 26 JUNE 2012 DTG (date time group) 

"[[ 210v13:2012]],"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\D?` to match any non-digit as your delimiter. This would be a more simplified SSN validator:

```
^(?!219\D?09\D?9999|078\D?05\D?1120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})d{3}\D?(?!00)\d{2}\D?(?!0{4})\d{4}$
```

This article might be helpful: http://rion.io/2013/09/10/validating-social-security-numbers-through-regular-expressions-2/

The article also gives a more over-the-top solution, which may be what your are looking for:

```
^(?!\b(\d)1+\D?(\d)1+\D?(\d)1+\b)(?!123\D?45\D?6789|219\D?09\D?9999|078\D?05\D?1120)(?!666|000|9d{2})\d{3}\D?(?!00)\d{2}\D?(?!0{4})\d{4}$
```

Comment: What about a delimiter for just dashes and spaces? I'm wondering if that will help screen out some of the things we are currently catching

Comment: Yes, the `\D` delimiter is pretty general. An alternative to only match a single space or a single `-` character would be to replace `\D?` with `[ -]?` for all occurrences of `\D?`.